# Android App Made in Qt Not Launching

Tags: android, qt, android-emulator, qtquickcontrols

I am getting started with developing an application for Android using Qt 5.8 and am running into issues running a basic application. When I run a basic application on an Android emulator, the application fails to load and a lot of errors are printed to the Qt console. [Text file of errors](https://github.com/Cabrosa1/QtIssue/blob/master/QtIssue.txt) 
[Images of Qt Creator, emulator, and errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P655B.jpg)

 
I followed tutorials online on getting the Android development environment set up, and as far as I know, I have the SDK, the NDK, Java, and ant all set up correctly.

From "create a project" in Qt, I selected the Qt Quick Control Application, and set the kit for Androidx86 and desktop. I basically kept the application as it came, but added a teal background and two text fields, but didn't change any code. 

When I run the program for desktop, it works fine and opens as shown with clickable buttons and typeable text fields. But when I try to deploy the application on any emulated Android application on 7.1, the emulator boots properly but the app that displays is just this.

The error messages that show up in the Qt Designer are and here is a file dump of the whole list of errors that showed up from trying to run the app. 

I am unable to figure out what these errors mean, as I installed Qt and the android files according to the documentation but still encountered these errors and was hoping someone would know what the issue was?

Comment: Do you need the App to run on x86 Android? I havent used Qt since 5.2 but it never really worked for me on x86 Android, on ARM Android was fine... What actual Android devices are x86 anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Probably related to the service change or similar (QtActivity etc.) Please check the following link. (Bug fixed and resolved) Fix version:  5.7.0 RC

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-52373